# AppsGeyser - cache not working

Tags: html

I have Web App that cache as per HTML5 on iPhone and Android and desktop browsers

the manefestfile is called  cache.manifest

I have arrived at that as it is supported both on android and iPhone

I see AppsGeyser now say that their product support HTML5 apps but when I create an app and load on Android the AppsGeyser app says UNCAHCED

Anyone got cache working on AppsGeyser

Comment: Our developers have been hard at work, and they've solved this issue.
Feel free to contact us if you have any further need for assistance.
Leah Goodman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 is a good chose for mobile development. The best thing about HTML5 is that you can move  any time to another framework. I can suggest PhoneGap ( http://www.phonegap.com/start/ ) as a stable one.

You can find a lot of such frameworks listed on Wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_phone_web_based_application_framework

Comment: Yes I know that one and have done it in phonegap.  Shame AppsGeyser dose not work.